# L’indifférent by Marcel Béalu

Tags: littérature, poésie, figure-de-style

I'm reading a poem named *L’indifférent* by Marcel Béalu. It's interesting as it seems to talk about unrealistic things, in a, roughly, illogical way, not to mention that its rhyme pattern is also unusual.

I'm wondering, is it a Nonsense Poems, something like The Owl and the Pussy-Cat''?

The full content of the poem is as below.

> L’indifférent
>
> Marcel Béalu
>
> J'ai un cheval noir et trois ânes blancs
> Dans une maison près d’un étang rose
>
> Le cheval peut galoper dans la lune
> Les trois ânes blancs trotter sur l’étang
>
> Je n’aime plus que le vent de novembre
> Courant après les passants de Paris
>
> Et l’ombre que fait ma plume en grinçant

P.s. I don't know which category this question belongs to, so if it's improper here, I'm sorry.

Comment: The fourth line is missing a word. As it appeared in _Ocarina_, it reads:  
_Les trois ânes **blancs** trotter sur l’étang_

Comment: @Segorian thank you , updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il s'agirait du genre [fantaisiste](https://short-edition.com/fr/categorie/poetik/fantaisiste), c'est à dire ce poème particulier pourrait être classé comme relevant de ce genre ; il ne faut pas déduire de cela que l'œuvre entière de l'auteur appartiendrait à cette école.

[L'école fantaisiste](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_fantaisiste) est un mouvement d'origine récente.

> Le groupe se définissait par son refus du romantisme et du symbolisme, du naturalisme et du positivisme. À ces grands courants du XIXe siècle, ils opposent la fantaisie (au sens large), le retour au burlesque. Ils adoptent des formes poétiques souples, ils privilégient le rythme et la chanson, tentant de trouver un équilibre entre sentimentalité, humour et mélancolie. Loin de l'hermétisme et du pessimisme des symbolistes et des décadents, les fantaisistes s'intéressent à la vie quotidienne, aux mots familiers, à l'imprévu et adoptent une grande liberté dans la versification tout en restant attachés aux thèmes de la patrie et de la nation.

Cet auteur est en fait plus connu comme appartenant à l'école du fantastique et on pourrait penser que le poème tient du fantastique, bien que d'autres ne voudraient voir dans ces lac roses et ânes qui marchent sur l'eau que des exagérations propres à rendre la fin du poème plus suggestive.

([La Clef d'Argent](http://clefdargent.free.fr/bealu.php)) Marcel Béalu est, avec Jean Ray, Claude Seignolle, A. Pieyre de Mandiargues, ou Michel de Ghelderode, l'une des grandes figures de la littérature fantastique d'expression française du siècle dernier.

(
[La pierre et le sel - Actualité et histoire de la poésie](https://pierresel.typepad.fr/la-pierre-et-le-sel/2011/12/marcel-b%C3%A9alu-un-po%C3%A8te-de-l%C3%A9cole-de-rochefort.html)
) Robert Sabatier le place [Marcel Bélaru], dans son Histoire de la poésie du 20° siècle, dans le chapitre des poètes prosateurs, bien qu’il ait, dit-il, écrit autant de poèmes en vers que de prose. Influencé par le surréalisme, il a été, cependant, un des maîtres du poème en prose, racontant la vie ordinaire sur un ton narratif très personnel, avec tous ses aspects quotidiens, simples et anodins en apparence, mais dont le caractère profond peut tout à coup basculer dans l’insolite, le burlesque, l’onirisme ou l’effrayant.